# Disable nested scrolling provided by v-13 support file

Tags: android, android-support-library

I migrated an eclipse project to Android Studio and updated the support libraries. The project had some nested scrolling functionality which was not supported then. Now the support library itself provides support for nested scrolling so that is causing problem. All the screens which have nested fuctionality, get scrolled to to top when opened. In eclipse support-v13 was added as jar files in the libs folder. I checked the jar file also. It does not have version no. Is there any way to disable nested scrolling provided by the support library?

**Update**

Tried by setting `setNestedScrollingEnabled()` false, but that did not made any difference. Moreover, this method is available from API 21 onwards. How can I get original functionality. Te problem is I cannot change everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem solved, used `android:focusableInTouchMode=true`